# Set class on View in xib file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xib

I have a project in Xcode 4.5 with storyboard.

I want to use a separate xib file for one piece of UI (long story) but I don't know how to connect this to the ViewController for this file. I created a separate FooViewController which is a subclass of UIViewController. However, it won't let me set this as the class for my xib (I get a beep indicating the name is invalid)

[image]

Weirdly, I can set it to some nonsense string that isn't a class in my project!? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One of two problems. 1. Are you sure you're selecting the view controller? If you delete the custom class, what does Xcode indicate as the default class? I wonder if you're selecting the view controller itself, but rather, maybe selecting the view, or something else. Make sure you click on the left most icon underneath the scene to choose the view controller, and the default class should be `UIViewController` (or something like that). Then you should be able to put in your custom view controller. 2 Alternatively, your custom `FooViewController` might not have a `UIViewController` base class.

Answer (score 1):

Rob answered in the comments to my question. Basically I was setting the class for the View and not the File's Owner as I should have been.

Comment: Give the comment a +1 so he gets some credit for answering it there - I did too.